# How to bind the 'Enter key' in Bash readline?

Tags: bash, keyboard-shortcuts

So I learned how to use bind yesterday.

By typing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd> followed by a key in the terminal, I get a raw character that represents the key. For example: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd> followed by <kbd>Esc</kbd> returns `^[`.

My question is, how can I bind the "enter key". The Enter Key returns `^M` but when I type the command

```
bind '"\e^M":"foobar"'
```

pressing the enter key does not result in foobar being typed in my terminal.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
bind '"\e^M":"foobar"'
```

binds Escape-Enter, not Enter. You just want

```
bind '"^M":"foobar"'
```

`^M` must be the actual control character, not `^` and `M`. A little easier to type is

```
bind '"\C-M":"foobar"'
```

Comment: Hey thanks Chepner, I was wondering why ^M did not work. Also, I was wondering where can I found out more about \C and \e and any other escape sequence characters.

Comment: See Readline Notation in the `bash` man page. Looks like "C-M" is sufficient; I'm not sure if "\C-M" is an acceptable alternative, or if the "\C" is just treated by `bash` as an escaped "C" which is treated as a "C".

Answer (score 0):

```
$ alias ^M='echo foobar'
$ ^M
foobar
```